# I want them to hover one by one

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Now my code crashes when hovering over all I use to mapitem down image data. I only want one hover at a time. when hovering over What should I do?
this is my code

```
function ImgCard(props) {

    const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(true);

    const handleMouseEnter = () => {
        setIsHovered(false);
    };

    const handleMouseLeave = () => {
        setIsHovered(true);
    };

    return (
        <div>

            <Container sx={{ pt: 5 }}>
                <Card p={5}>

                    <Container>

                            <Container>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid container spacing={2}>
                                            <Grid item key={item} xs={6} md={3}>
                                                <Card
                                                    sx={{ height: '100%', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}
                                                    style={{ color: "gray", textAlign: "center" }}
                                                >
                                                    <CardMedia

                                                        component="img"
                                                        sx={{
                                                            pt: '10.9%',

                                                        }}
                                                        image={item.src}
                                                        onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
                                                        onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
                                                        style={{
                                                            filter: isHovered ? 'brightness(75%)' : 'none',
                                                            transition: 'filter 0.3s ease-in-out'
                                                        }}
                                                        alt="random"
                                                    />
                                                </Card>
                                            </Grid>
```

I sat down for 3 days and I really couldn't fix it. Really out of wit

Comment: Can you post an example of what the `props` argument of your function is supposed to look like?

Comment: sorry i don't know I'm studying react, can you explain more?

Comment: `function ImgCard(props) {...}` in your code has `props` as an argument. What exactly is `props`?